# Complexity of lists in haskell in Data.map

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary, time-complexity

Sorry if this seems like an obvious question.

I was creating a Data.map of lists {actually a tuple of an integer and a list (Integer, [(Integer, Integer)])} for implementing a priority queue + adjacency list for some graph algorithms like Dijkstras and Prims,

The Data.map is implemented using binary trees(I read that) so I just want to confirm that when doing the map operations (I believe they will be rotations) the interpreter does not do deep copies of the list just shallow copies of the references of lists right?

I am doing this to implement a prims algorithm in haskell which will run in O(nlogn + mlogn) time where n = no. of vertices and m = no. of edges, in a purely functional way,
If the lists are stored in the priority queue the algorithm will work in that time. Most haskell implementations I found online, dont achieve this complexity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Haskell itself doesn't promise anything about that, but no implementation I know of does a deep copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the lists will not be copied every time you create a new `Map`, at least if you're using GHC (other implementations probably do this correctly as well). This is one of the advantages of a purely functional language: because data can't be rewritten, data structures don't need to be copied to avoid problems you might have in an imperative language. Consider this snippet of Lisp:

```
(setf a (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(setf b a)
; a and b are now both '(1 2 3 4 5).
(setf (cadr a) 0)
; a is now '(1 0 3 4 5).
; Careful though! a and b point to the same piece of memory,
; so b is now also '(1 0 3 4 5). This may or may not be what you expected.
```

In Haskell, the only way to have mutable state like this is to use an explicitly mutable data structure, such as something in the `State` monad (and even this is sort of faking it (which is a good thing)). This potentially unexpected memory duplication issue is unthinkable in Haskell because once you declare that `a` is a particular list, it is that list now and forever. Because it is guaranteed to never change, there is no danger in reusing memory for things that are supposed to be equal, and in fact, GHC will do exactly this. Therefore, when you make a new `Map` with the same values, only pointers to the values will be copied, not the values themselves.

For more information, read about [the difference between Boxed and Unboxed types](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/primitives.html).

Answer (score 0):

1) `Integer` is slower then `Int`

2) If you have `[(Integer, [(Integer, Integer)])]`

You could create with `Data.Map` not only `Map Integer [(Integer, Integer)]`, but `Map Integer (Map Integer Integer)`

3) If you use `Int` instead of `Integer`, you could use a bit quicker data - `IntMap`from `Data.IntMap`: `IntMap (IntMap Int)`

4) complexity of each methods are written in description:
[Data.IntMap.Strict](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/ghc-doc/libraries/containers-0.5.0.0/Data-IntMap-Strict.html) and here [Data.IntMap.Lazy](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/ghc-doc/libraries/containers-0.5.0.0/Data-IntMap-Lazy.html):

```
map :: (a -> b) -> IntMap a -> IntMap b
O(n). Map a function over all values in the map.
```